# JavaFX TableView - Center the Content of a Table Column

Tags: javafx, center, tablecolumn

I have a big Problem.

I try to center the Content of a TableColumn in a TableView.

I already tried everything I found on the net but really nothing of that worked!

Is anyone there who had/has the same problem? any Solutions?

Hope for help!

Edit:

Well I was able to center the content of a static cell with this code:

```
tc_customer.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<TvAccounting, String>, TableCell<TvAccounting, String>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell<TvAccounting, String> call(TableColumn<TvAccounting, String> p) {
                    TableCell<TvAccounting, String> tc = new TableCell<TvAccounting, String>();
                    tc.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    tc.setText("SOMETEXT");
                    return tc;
                }
            });
```

But the content should come from a database and i really hav no idea how to get the data from the ObservableList Object that i use in the `TABLEVIEWNAME.setItems` method...

I first used this code:

```
tc_customer.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TvAccounting, String>("Customer"));
```

but there was no way to center that content!

Please could anyone help me?

Edit:

Thanks to this Great Answer, I did it!

Code below:

```
tc_customer.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<TvAccounting, String>, TableCell<TvAccounting, String>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell<TvAccounting, String> call(TableColumn<TvAccounting, String> p) {
                    TableCell<TvAccounting, String> tc = new TableCell<TvAccounting, String>(){
                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            if (item != null){
                                setText(item);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    tc.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    return tc;
                }
            });

            tc_customer.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TvAccounting, String>("Customer"));
```

**BEST THANKS!!!**

Comment: Edit your question to include info on what you have tried and what environment you are running in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CellValueFactory and CellFactory are two different things. 
CellValueFactory is used to specify where do the values come from, while CellFactory specifies how do they get displayed.

Use both at the same time. But in the `setCellFactory`  code you should **not** do `setText` . Setting the text will be taken care of by the `TableCell` code inside the `updateItem()` method. This method will use the value that is provided from the ' cellValueFactory ' and take care of setting it inside its own label.

```
tc_customer.setCellFactory(
   new Callback< TableColumn<TvAccounting, String>,
                 TableCell<TvAccounting, String>>()
   {
      @Override public TableCell<TvAccounting, String>
      call(TableColumn<TvAccounting, String> p) {
         TableCell<TvAccounting, String> tc =
            new TableCell<TvAccounting, String>();
         tc.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
         // tc.setText("SOMETEXT"); This line should be removed
         return tc;
      }
   }
);
```

Comment: Okay... I'm a newby at JFX so where should I declare the updateItem() Method?? Relly have no idea

Comment: Should I do that in my `TvAccounting` entity?

Comment: That's the point. You shouldn't need to declare the updateItem(). It should work just by removing the setText code above. UpdateItem is an internal method in TableCell. You would only need to override it if you are writing your own TableCell implementation. Which isn't your case.